# How to insert object as html page into html element which is coming from back-end after sending request as POST (and not GET)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm sending parameters from frontend and receiving a html object as response from backend. My request parameters are large text fragments which I must send as POST request parameters, or request object and I cannot send them as url path parameters with GET method for some reasons (like too large text, security and secrecy).
Say I have in Html:

```
<button ng-click=" myFunction (myParam1, myParam2)">Send </button>
 <div id="myElement"></div>
```

in script:

```
function (myParam1, myParam2){
    var myParams={' myParam1':  myParam1, ' myParam2': myParam2};
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/postparameters",
        data: myParams
    }).then(function(data) {
        document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = data;           
    })
};
```

In my backend (java Spring) I process parameters and return String object that is html text. There is no problem with backend (it return proper html text and I tested and it).
Problem is how to receive html object in my html element?
When I try it I'm getting like [object Object].

As an option (that could receive html object in html element) but I cannot use here, in this case: If I use ng-include=" 'url' " (and url from my backend) then I could only include parameters in url as path parameters, I could only use GET method. But in my case I need to use POST. Can I use ng-include with POST or use something else that can work with POST and avoiding parameters in url path?

Comment: Today is a good day to learn how to debug things for yourself, because StackOverflow is not about to debug your programs for you. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thanks. There is another problem here: with debugging of promises: .then(function(response.data) where $http will return a response.data. I could not be able to see the object data in debug, whatever I tried. But I could see what was send by backend when debugging backend. And besides I could be able to get the response in ng-include whe using get method instead og post ot dirty way in form - iframe when when post. But couldn't with $http - html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = data.data;
```